# External drives & mobile phone open f spot, not the file manager. 

Tags: unity

When I click on unity icon for external drive or mobile phone, f spot is used as default which shows nothing.

How do I get the icons to open the file manager instead, which is what used to happen on 11.04?

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry i cannot give you the correct English names - i use Ubuntu in german.

If you open the system stuff (first entry on the menu on top right) u will find something on external mediums - there you can choose that it should always ask you what to do with medias.

Answer (score 0):

Ty this. Go to COMPUTER, then can you see all your hard disk, external drive and mobile phone, right click on properties(of your external drive for example) , click on "open with" then you can see f.spot.. in default applications, right click on f spot and press forget association. You can add open with ·files· and will open your external devices as folders,  I hope this help u :)